# Deprecation of Android's Canvas.clipRect()

Tags: android, android-canvas

Since Android's API 26 `Canvas.clipRect(float, float, float, float, Region.Op)` is deprecated. In my custom view I use that method with `Region.Op.REPLACE` as last argument. I just want to know possible replacement of that deprecated method call with same functionality. I did not find clear answer for my question in documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding from the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect) - is that expanding the canvas clip size (with Region.Op.REPLACE) was never a desired use case, as the suggested replacement methods do not have that functionality.

However, you can continue to draw outside the clip bounds in your custom view and request the parent view does not clip it's children with

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

Comment: But what's the alternative to this function call (of "clipRect" with Region.Op.REPLACE) ? If they deprecate it, what should be used instead?